# Getting recurrence last occurence end date of meeting Series in graph

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I'm writing an application to help users scheduling recurring events leveraging the dotnet sdk for Microsoft Graph.
With code similar to this, I'm scheduling a recurring event using a NumberOfOccurences to limit the number of meetings that will be created.

```
var updatingEvent = new Event
{
     Subject = "test",
     Location = new Location { DisplayName = "Montreal" },
     IsAllDay = false,
     Start = getTimeZoneFromDateTime(DateTime.Now, tzLabel),
     End = getTimeZoneFromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), tzLabel),
     OnlineMeetingUrl = "someurl",
     Body = new ItemBody { Content = emailBody.HtmlBody, ContentType = BodyType.Html },
     ShowAs = FreeBusyStatus.Busy,
     Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence
            {
                Range = new RecurrenceRange
                {
                    StartDate = new Date(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day),
                    Type = RecurrenceRangeType.Numbered,
                    NumberOfOccurrences = 3
                },
                Pattern = new RecurrencePattern
                {
                     Interval = 1,
                    Type = RecurrencePatternType.Daily
                }
            };
};
```

**I'd like to get the EndDate of the last Occurrence (or the recurrence end date) without have to query all the occurrences and/or having to calculate it on my side.**
This way I'd be able to query instances without having to iterate and/or set an arbitrary date.

```
var request = graphClient.Users[Settings.SkypeUserEmail].Calendar
                                               .Events[updatedEvent.id]
                                               .Instances
                                               .Request();
request.QueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("startDateTime", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("s")));
request.QueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("endDateTime", DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString("s")));
```

Thanks for your help!
    var instancesPage = await request.GetAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought dan-silver would update his answer to indicated it's currently not possible.
If you create a recurring event with a number of occurrences set, the end date will be null. **So you either have to throw random query dates at the API or query all occurrences in order to get the overall end date of the series**. It would be something nice to add in future versions of the Graph.

Answer (score 0):

Update: The answer below won't work since the `endDate` is null when setting the series with the `numberOfOccurences` parameter.

I don't see a direct way to query the last occurrence, but something like this might work. Basically query the instances of the series over a large time period and select the last one.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/[series master id]/instances?startdatetime=2010-01-01T00:00:00&enddatetime=2020-01-01T00:00:00&$orderby=start/dateTime desc&$top=1`

---

There's a `recurrence` object in the series event that has an `endDate` field. For example:
[image: example recurrence JSON]

If you don't have the series event, you can find the `seriesMasterId` property that corresponds to the series on any recurrence event.

Relevant links:

- [RecurrenceRange object](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/recurrencerange) documentation
- [Example of recurrence in the Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/events/AQMkADRmZWM1ODE4LWQ4YWItNDlkYS1iZTY4LWVhZWEzYjRlODgAMzkARgAAAwuZXteXVEJLqYcO_ELlrI4HAG5bRHPEmFRPh7PkFZALEj0AAAIBDQAAAG5bRHPEmFRPh7PkFZALEj0AAAJo7wAAAA==&method=GET&version=v1.0) (click `Run Query` then scroll down)

Comment: Thanks for that answer. that basically means you have to provide an arbitrary end date. That's far from optimal from a reliability standpoint.  My understanding is there is currently no way to get the last occurrence of a series without providing an arbitrary end date or querying all the data, correct?